# CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES error on NVIDIA

Tags: opencl, nvidia

I am trying to run a code on NVIDIA GPUs. I am getting `CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES` error when executing `CL_COMMAND_READ_BUFFER` repeatedly. The same code did run on Intel CPU with 8 computation units flawlessly.

On CPU:

- local size = 1
- global size = 8
- `DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE` = 12431327232

On GPU:

- local size = 32 (warp size)
- global size = 32*8
- `DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE` = 1072889856

I know `CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES` error is because of memory accesses outside of allocated buffers. But I am not sure why this error is seen only in GPU. what could the mistake be? Am I missing anything?

EDIT:

The struct data of h_ref[add] read is not as expected.On printing sizeof(h_ref) on host side returns 8 on the device side returns 4. It reads 8 on host and device when run on Intel CPU. How can i ensure proper transfer of data ?

specs GeForce GTX 560 Ti
http://www.pastebin.ca/2892740

Kernel code :

```
__kernel void product(__global double* h_inputvec,__global struct Reference* h_ref ,__global double* h_res,const int num_ipvec,const int N,const int numb)
 {  
 const int indicator = get_group_id(0);

const int add = (int)(indicator*num_ipvec)/N;
unsigned int ipv_size = h_ref[add].num ;

const int fract = (int)(ipv_size*N/num_ipvec); 
int fractn = (int) fract/numb;
const int div = (int)ipv_size/fractn  ; 

struct Node temp = h_ref[add].noderef ; 


__local double centroid[441];
double value;
int tempo ;

const int th_id = get_local_id(0);
int te = 14;

for(int i=0; i< 14 ; i++) // assuming that number of work items allotted are greater than centroids
{
    int val =  (441*(indicator % numb));
    centroid[(32*i+th_id)%441] = temp.centroids[(32*i+th_id)%441 + val] ;
}   


for( int i = 0 ; i<= div ; i++)
{           
    value = 0;
    int inc = (int) (indicator / numb);
    tempo = h_ref[add].input_vec[(i*fractn+inc)%ipv_size];


    for(int j=0 ; j<441 ;j++)
    {                       
        double diff = centroid[j]- h_inputvec[441*tempo + j];
        value += pow(diff,2);
    }
    double norm =  sqrt(value);
    h_res[N*tempo+(indicator%numb)] =  norm;
}
```

}

Host code:

```
 struct Node {
 public:
 cl_uint num
 cl_double *dic;
 cl_double *c;
 cl_double *di;
 cl_double *bs;
 Node *bs;
 };

 struct Reference{
 public:
 cl_uint* inec;
 cl_uint nu;
 Node nref;
 };

     N=8
     size_t local[1] = {32};
     size_t global[1] = {32*8};

    size_t sz_ipv = 441*num_ipvec*sizeof(double);
    size_t sz_ref = sizeof(temp_ref);
    size_t  sz_res = N*num_ipvec*sizeof(double); 
    size_t sz_minres = num_ipvec*sizeof(int)*(N/2);

    /* create host array */

    double *h_inputvec = (double*) calloc(441*num_ipvec,sizeof(double));
    Reference *h_ref = (Reference*) calloc(1,sizeof(temp_ref)); // change
    double *h_res = (double*) calloc(N*num_ipvec,sizeof(double)); // N,X data forward
    int *h_minres = (int*) calloc(num_ipvec*(N/2),sizeof(int));

            for(int in =0 ; in<N*num_ipvec ; in++) // initialze result to maximum value (padding) 
    {
            h_res[in] = numeric_limits<int>::max();
            h_minres[in%(N/2*num_ipvec)] = in % int(N/2) ;
    }

    cl_mem c_inputvec = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sz_ipv, h_inputvec, &err);
    cl_mem c_ref = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,sz_ref, h_ref, &err);
    cl_mem c_res = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,sz_res, h_res, &err);
    cl_mem c_minres =  clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,sz_minres, h_minres, &err);


    // set arguments    

    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &c_inputvec);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &c_ref);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &c_res);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, sizeof(const int), &num_ipvec);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 4, sizeof(const int), &N);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 5, sizeof(const int), &numb);
    printf(" arguments to kernel \n");

    //launch kernel         
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, dim, 0, global, local, 0, (cl_event*)NULL, &event_time);
```

Comment: Post the relevant code. Try to produce a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am curious to know if  CL_OF_RESOURCES error. can it be because of insufficient memory or just memory access outside allocated buffers ?

Comment: We are curious to see your code. We could just make up possible reasons why you see the error, but that’s not productive. In the meantime, I can give you only one pointer: [Google `CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES`.](https://www.google.com/search?q=cl_out_of_resources) I did a quick search and found [a post](https://www.khronos.org/message_boards/showthread.php/9255-cl_out_of_resources?p=30035&viewfull=1#post30035) mentioning that *if you use NVIDIA hardware, `CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES` is a kind of “generic” error returned by the driver when something is wrong*. This only makes my point stronger. Show the code!

Comment: The arracy `double centroid[441]` declared in your kernel requires 3528 bytes of private memory, i.e. 882 32-bit registers on an Nvidia GPU.  As per the Nvidia CUDA 6.0 Programming Guide, there isn't an Nvidia GPU is existence that can have that many registers per thread.  That is at least one cause of `CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES`.

Comment: I have edited the code to use local memory instead. I am still getting the same error. shared memory per block for this NVIDIA GPU: 49152 bytes.